# What additional percentage of the suns energy is being trapped via green house gases?

Tags: energy, entropy, climate-science

Every year we release more greenhouse gases which causes the atmosphere to trap more energy and thus warm the planet.

What additional percentages of energy are we talking about here? I would assume fractions of a percentage point, which still is massive on a planet scaled system, but I really don't know.

Comment: Figures around a couple of $\mathrm{W/m^2}$ are what people bandy about, but I am never sure if this is averaged over the entire surface or not and whether it includes aerosols &c (which have negative effects). TOA solar flux is about $1360\,\mathrm{W/m^2}$, and this *isn't* averaged (so this is what hits the top of the atmosphere at the point directly facing the Sun).  (This isn't an answer because it's full of 'I don't know's!)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The IPCC estimates that a doubling of CO$_2$ concentration means a radiative forcing of $3.7\ {\rm W}/{\rm m}^2$.

Although CO$_2$ has not quite doubled yet, the world is halfway there, according to [Myhre et al](https://www.nilu.no/Nyhetsarkiv/tabid/74/language/en-GB/NewsId/863/Halfway-to-doubling-of-COsub2sub-radiative-forcing.aspx) (2017). If one also considers other greenhouse gases, they say that the combined radiative forcing from all well-mixed greenhouse gases presently, is 84% of the radiative forcing of a CO$_2$ doubling.

Average radiation by the surface is about $400\ {\rm W}/{\rm m}^2$. So currently, we are about a percent of that.

Radiation increases as $T^4$, so one percent increase in radiation corresponds to 0.25 % increase in temperature, $0.7^\circ$C.